# Doctrine2 how to build an UPDATE query with IN?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Im trying to UPDATE multiple lines with 1 query. This is what i got so far:

```
// assume $ids is an array with integer values

$q->update('Application\Entity\Message', 'm')
      ->set('a.dateRead', $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
      ->where('a.id IN :ids')
      ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
      ->getQuery()
      ->execute();
```

This does not seem to work, i think its because setParameter does not accept an array?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding colons around the parameter, like:

```
->where('a.id IN (:ids)')
```